# how to pass javascript variable to php with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to pass javascript variable to php file. Here I attached my code

```
function Calculate(val)
    {

        var h = document.getElementById('xyz').textContent ;
        var result = h * val;
        result = result.toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById('lblRes').innerHTML ='$'+ result;
        $('#ori_price').hide();

        $.ajax ({
            url: 'nonmembersdetail1.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {val : h},
            success: function( result ) {
                alert( result );
            }
        });
   }

<?php
echo "<td ><label id='xyz' name='xyz'>".  $row->nonmember_price  ."</label></td>";
echo "<td ><input type='text' style='width:40px' id='words' name='qty' value='1' onchange='Calculate(this.value);'  /></td>";
?>
```

In my `nonmembersdetail1.php` code

```
echo ( $_POST['val'] );
```

I didn't get value in php file. Please anyone help me.Thanks in advance...

Comment: `echo json_encode($_POST['val']);`

Comment: Use an absolute URL. Also, does the alert fire?

Comment: 1. add PHP error reporting. 2. check the network tab and console tab for errors 3. use jQuery now you have it anyway: `var h = $('#xyz').text()
        var result = h * val;
        result = result.toFixed(2);
        $('#lblRes').html('$'+ result);` - this assumes xyz is a tag and not an input field

Comment: var h = document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML; ?

Comment: i wrote echo json_encode($_POST['val']); I got null value

Comment: Show the HTML so we can see what xyz is

Comment: hey, I edited my code please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Check in you browser console, if the AJAX call is actually getting fired or you are getting any error before that. Because there is no error in the AJAX call and you should get the val value in POST array of PHP.

Comment: I got value in my javascript alert box which is i want to in php

Comment: if it is alert , it means it is success fully responded by php ?? then what's the problem ? @user3424093

Comment: ya exactly. I m also confused. In my php file i got null value.

Comment: I got value in my javascript alert which is I print in my php code. I m so tired to get this error. bcz i got return value.i.e in shows alert box. but i want it in my php code that is not getting.. please help me.

Comment: Are you getting the exact value in the alert box? If yes then you should get that value in php file too. Try to test it by loading the PHP file URL directly and passing the value in URL parameter. Also change $_POST to $_GET. This way you be able to see if there is any PHP error directly on page itself. Do it just to test.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered, that you are using the variable `result` twice? One in your code before you fire the ajax-call and once inside the ajax-calls response. Change the name of the variable and tell us how that worked.

```
function Calculate(val)
{

    var h = document.getElementById('xyz').textContent ;
    var amount = h * val;
    amount = amount.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('lblRes').innerHTML ='$'+ amount ;
    $('#ori_price').hide();

    $.ajax ({
        url: 'nonmembersdetail1.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {val : h},
        success: function( result ) {
            alert( result );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed result variable name. but still not working.. please help me.